# How to run a Knex migration conditionally

Tags: database-migration, knex.js

I mistakenly deleted a migration that added columns to a group table, and then had to add it back on my local db. However, on production, the migration was not mistakenly deleted, so now it throws an error when it runs the added migration.

Recognizing there is probably a more elegant solution, at this point, I want simply to add a conditional that runs this added migration only if the added columns do not exist.

Here is the current added migration:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.table('groups', function(t) {
    t.specificType('fulltext', 'tsvector');
    t.index('fulltext', null, 'gin');
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.table('groups', function(t) {
    t.dropColumn('fulltext');
    t.dropIndex([ 'fulltext' ]);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just recreate / populate your local DB... but anyways if you really want to do this, you need to use https://knexjs.org/#Schema-hasColumn

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.hasColumn('tablename', 'columnname')
    .then(res => {
      if (res) {
        return; // skip
      }
      return knex.schema.table('groups', function(t) {
        t.specificType('fulltext', 'tsvector');
        t.index('fulltext', null, 'gin');
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks very much! Perfect answer. tells me what I should do, but also what I could do!